# direct remote connection to postgresql 12 on a raspberry

Tags: postgresql

I get no (direct) connection to my postgresql 12 database on a remote raspberry.

I do get a connection to it by means of a program called Postico with these settings:

```
host    : localhost
port    : 5432
user    : the username on the raspberry
pwd     : the password of the user on the raspberry
Database: the name of my database
SSH Host: the IP of my raspberry
port    : 22
user    : the username on the raspberry
pwd     : the password of the user on the raspberry
```

So I get access via the SSH-whatever, but I want to get direct access as I want to access it also via sqlAlchemy in my python program. But there I get the FATAL Error message that it can't connect.

So ist there a chance to get direct access to the database? Do I need to give the user of my host-computer permissions in the pg-hba.config and the postgresql.config on the raspberry?

So I'd like to get in with these settings:

```
host    : the IP of my raspberry
port    : 5432
user    : the username on the raspberry
pwd     : the password of the user on the raspberry
Database: the name of my database
```

Comment: Can you connect via `psql -U user_on_db -h the_database_machine` ? Can you ping / telnet / nmap the remote machine ? is port 54332 open? Is it visible to the outside world?

Comment: Yes. I can ping the machine, the port 5432 is open and it's visible to the outside world. But I can't connect via this psql -U command. But there is no password. I'd be surprised if this would work. Nevertheless, my host computer says: command not found. So maybe I need to install psql on my host computer? Or maybe I need to set a path? But I also have another database on my host computer and I can connect to this.

Comment: I also can log into the machine and psql the database there.

Comment: Yes, you'll need some kind of client on your *local* machine. Could be psql, or some psycopg client for python , or PDO for PHP. Whatever. (BTW, I have never heard of Postico ...)

Comment: Thank you! So I'll try this. 
(https://eggerapps.at/postico/ is a trial to provide an apple-pretty Postgresql-client.)